# Install Tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have a GPU nvidia Geforce 820m in my notebook. I want to install tensorflow on my Ubuntu 16.04. I am not sure should I install GPU or non-GPU version?
It has compute capability of 2.1 but tensorflow requires above 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has compute capability < 3.0 TF will not work as described in the [installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux)

Using TF with GPU-support isn't always faster. If you have a fast, multicore CPU you might not profit from GPU-support when training small networks. It takes time to load the data into GPU store, significantly longer then copying data into CPU-RAM. For deep networks this is irrelevant and GPU will be faster.

I have a laptop with a quad-core i7 (6th gen) and a GTX 960M, small networks like the ones used in the MNIST Tutorials from Google overall train slower when using GPU, because the data has to be loaded first.

Plus, installing TF with GPU support takes considerably more time than a simple `pip3 install tensorflow`.

Answer (score 1):

With gpu support trust me way faster

just make sure to install proprietary drivers first for your card